# Javascript performance: Variable vs Large object's attribute

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, attributes

I am building a number of HTML5 games and I am not sure about one thing in javascript.

When dealing with a large object (with a lot of attributes and methods), is it somehow different, if I store the attribute value in a variable?

Say I have to check for some value in `application.data.setings.foo.bar` multiple times per second. Should I store it in a variable `fooBar`? If I understand it correctly, the variable would be just a reference, so it shouldn't matter.

so: ***Should you store values of large objects' attributes in variables?***

Comment: The classic "try it and measure the results" likely applies here. However as long as you are not searching for it each time, I'd like to believe it will perform fine.

Answer (score 3):

This diagram give you your answer. http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html#access_times_for_object_properties_by_de

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking is:

If you have a variable called:

`application.data.settings.foo.bar = { some: 'value' }`

Is it more performant to access it by using `application.data.settings.foo.bar` - or to instead say: `var bar = application.data.settings.foo.bar` and then refer to `bar`.

My guess is that the assignment to variable is probably slightly more performant - simply because there are less steps for the interpreter to take in order to access the relevant item. If you use `application.data.settings.foo.bar` - the interpreter has to utilize the reference to the `application` object, then reference it's `data` property, then reference its `setting` property, then reference its `foo` property, then reference its `bar` property. This is 5 steps.

If you reference it into a local variable for access - you are still hitting the same object, but you are hitting it directly on each reference.

At the end of the day, however, this is unlikely to be a performance enhancement which is hugely noticeable, unless you are doing a lot of heavy, rapid-access looping or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

For numbers you may see a performance improvement if you place it in a variable